# Registration PHP Code error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am facing an error while completing my registration system. My database connection is working properly.

Registration PHP Code:

```
require 'db.php';

$message = '';

if(!empty($_POST['full_name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['confirm_password'])):

    // Enter the new user in the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, email, username, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['full_name']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

if( $stmt->execute() ):
header('Location: index.php');
    $message = 'Successfully created new user';
else:
    $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
endif;

endif;
```

Comment: In the future please add your error in your post to help with the debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You are binding parameters for values which you have not included in the query,

change,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, email, username, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
```

to,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, email, username, password) VALUES (:full_name, :email, :username, :password)";
```

and change,

```
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['full_name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

to,

```
$stmt->bindParam(':full_name', $_POST['full_name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

Now you are actually passing the correct values to the query.

Take note of the following:

- Ensure you are validating/sanitizing your user input.
- Ensure that you use `exit` with `header` to prevent errors.
- You are setting the value of `$message` but not outputting it.